# zip file generated by java program

Tags: zip, file-extension

I need to open the files on click directly after extracting from the zip file without the pop up( Select a program to open).

Explanation:

I have a document named documentName.doc . I have uploaded and saved it as documentName without the extension. After zipping and extracting the files, i am not able to open the files directly. Its showing a pop up box (Select a program to open).

Is there a way that i can open the document directly.

Comment: rename it and add the file extension. btw, this seems to belong to the Super User. Flagging.

Comment: If the document extension is provided, will it open directly? @glee

Comment: Yes of course. Google for file association for more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will post the result after trying it. @glee8e

Comment: Yes your suggestion worked out. thanks a lot @glee8e